# Need help to determine whether PWM frequency is suitable

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc-motor, dc-dc-converter, frequency

I am using a solar panel as the power source for making a simple DC motor based fan

Parameters of panel:

Voltage at max power point:8.2V

Nominal output voltage:6V

Max output current :0.62A

Max power=5W

My DC motor is rated at 3V. So i am planning to use a DC-DC Buck regulator with switching frequency of 200KHz for stepping down to 3V.The motor is of permanent magnet brushed type. It looks like this:[image]

DC motor parameters at 3V:

1A consumption at max efficiency

Stall current :~2A

I am planning to use MIC2177 buck regulator(of Microchip) at 3V output with conversion efficiency of >85%  at 3V output.

My questions are:
1) Is the switching frequency too high or low for this application?
Are there any problems which i might encounter during operation?
(Or , am i misunderstanding things here?)
2) Which  flyback diode should i connect  in parallel to the motor?

Comment: While switching techniques are common in motor driving, using a DC-DC converter is not.  Usually a motor is selected with a winding suitable to the source voltage, or the motor itself is driven with the actual PWM waveform, rather than an already filter-averaged DC voltage.   What is your source voltage and what is the actual application problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have updated my question. Please read it and help me.

Comment: One thing that you have not specified is how much current the motor draws when it is under load with the fan blades attached. If the power of the motor (volts * amps) is greater than the power delivery of the solar panel then this will never work. Any conversion circuitry also consumes power as well and so the conversion cannot be 100% efficient. Thus the solar panel capacity needs to be more than the power the motor will consume.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I have updated the question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adapt your PWM to output your required 3V for the motor, you have to calculate it as follows:

Duty Cycle = Vr / Vp where Vr: is the voltage required, Vp: peak voltage, and Duty Cycle: is the time of the wave to be switched on / the time to be off. So 3V / 8.2V = 0.36 and this will not make an issue while working since its just a DC fan motor.

About the required flyback diode, simply any diode will do the work required as long it can withstand the current passing through it. 1N4007 is good and safe, and also cost effective.

Comment: Can you explain me what i should do with the value of the duty cycle you calculated?According to the datasheet of the MIC2177 i am not able to find any option to set the duty cycle. What else should i do now?

Comment: I have answered your question according to the given information. To better describe what you have to do, you have to give me more information. So tell me what type of circuit are you using? Do you use solar panel controller? And what type if yes? Do you use a storage battery? Or you just power your motor when panel is at daylight.

Comment: Thanks for the info.There is no need to explain anything more. After looking up some of the terms on google i was able to understand things.

Comment: You are welcomed, good luck.